# Getting index of vector with delimited parts

Tags: r

I have vectors that looks like these variations:

```
cn1 <- c("Probe","Genes","foo","bar","Probe","Genes","foo","bar")
#          0        1      2     3      4      5       6    7

cn2 <- c("Probe","Genes","foo","bar","qux","Probe","Genes","foo","bar","qux")
#          0        1      2     3      4      5       6    7     8      9
```

Note that in each vector above consists of two parts. They are separated with `"Probe","Genes"`.
What I want to do is to get the indexes of the first part of the entry in between that separator. Yielding

```
cn1_id  ------> [2,3]
cn2_id  ------> [2,3,4]
```

How can I achieve that in R?

I tried this but it doesn't do what I want:

```
> split(cn1,c("Probe","Genes"))
$Genes
[1] "Genes" "bar"   "Genes" "bar"  

$Probe
[1] "Probe" "foo"   "Probe" "foo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that you can use. Note that R vectors are 1-based so counting starts at 1 rather than 0.

```
findidx <- function(x) {
    idx <- which(x=="Probe" & c(tail(x,-1),NA)=="Genes")
    if (length(idx)>1) {
        (idx[1]+2):(idx[2]-1)
    } else {
        NA # what to return if no match found
    }
}


findidx(cn1)
# [1] 3 4
findidx(cn2)
# [1] 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks. If the 2nd part are `"Probe.1" and "Genes.1"`. How can I modify your code to accomodate that? Actually I'm working on column name of dataframe. And R's DF will add extra `.1` for repeating column name.

Comment: Then you'll have to find the start and end separately. Just do another `which()` like i did above but with the different match names for the stop indicators.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `between` from `data.table`

```
indx <- between(cn1, 'Genes', 'Probe')
indx2 <- between(cn2, 'Genes', 'Probe')
which(cumsum(indx)==2)[-1]-1
#[1] 2 3

which(cumsum(indx2)==2)[-1]-1
#[1] 2 3 4
```